# TableView not showing values when using two Objects JAVAFX with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

I am trying to create a TableView in JavaFX, but after many attempts values are not showing without giving any Errors. 
If i create a TableView with only one Object declared (TableView) it works properly.

I already tried to create a "helper" class, which contained both objects as it's attributes, but still the same problem no errors just TableView not working.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
    public TableColumn<CarEntity, String> HistoryBrand;
    public TableColumn<CarEntity, String> HistoryColor;
    public TableColumn<CarEntity, Date> HistoryDate;
    public TableColumn<CarEntity,String> HistoryCategory;
    public TableColumn<CarEntity,Double> HistoryPrice;
    public TableColumn<OrdersArchiveEntity, Integer> HistoryCarScore;
    public TableColumn<OrdersArchiveEntity, Integer> HistoryOrderScore;
    public TableColumn<OrdersArchiveEntity, Date> HistoryRentalDate;
    public TableColumn<OrdersArchiveEntity, Date> HistoryReturnDate;
    public TableView HistoryTable;


    HistoryBrand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CarEntity, String>("mark"));
    HistoryColor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CarEntity,String>("color"));
    HistoryDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CarEntity, Date>("productionDate"));
    HistoryCategory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CarEntity, String>("category"));
    HistoryPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CarEntity, Double>("price"));
    HistoryCarScore.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrdersArchiveEntity,Integer>("carScore"));
    HistoryOrderScore.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrdersArchiveEntity,Integer>("orderScore"));
    HistoryRentalDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrdersArchiveEntity,Date>("rentalDate"));
    HistoryReturnDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OrdersArchiveEntity,Date>("returnDate"));


    Query queryHist = session.createQuery("select c, o from OrdersArchiveEntity o, CarEntity c where c.id=o.carByCarId.id");
    List HistoryList = queryHist.list();
    ObservableList Historia = FXCollections.observableArrayList(HistoryList);
    HistoryTable.setItems(Historia);
```

And here are my Classes

```
package DataBase;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Car", schema = "dbo", catalog = "master")
public class CarEntity {
    private int id;
    private RentalBaseEntity RentalBaseEntityByRentalBaseId;
    public String mark;
    public String color;
    public Date productionDate;
    public double price;
    private String category;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Mark", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(String mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Color", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Production_Date", nullable = false)
    public Date getProductionDate() {
        return productionDate;
    }

    public void setProductionDate(Date productionDate) {
        this.productionDate = productionDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Price", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Category", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CarEntity carEntity = (CarEntity) o;
        return id == carEntity.id &&
                Double.compare(carEntity.price, price) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(mark, carEntity.mark) &&
                Objects.equals(color, carEntity.color) &&
                Objects.equals(productionDate, carEntity.productionDate) &&
                Objects.equals(category, carEntity.category);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, mark, color, productionDate, price, category);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RentalBase_Id", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    public RentalBaseEntity getRentalBaseEntityByRentalBaseId() {
        return RentalBaseEntityByRentalBaseId;
    }
    public void setRentalBaseEntityByRentalBaseId(RentalBaseEntity here) {
        this.RentalBaseEntityByRentalBaseId = here;
    }
}
```

```
package DataBase;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "OrdersArchive", schema = "dbo", catalog = "master")
public class OrdersArchiveEntity {
    private int id;
    private int orderScore;
    private int carScore;
    private Date rentalDate;
    private Date returnDate;
    private CarEntity carByCarId;
    private SellerEntity sellerBySellerId;
    private ClientEntity clientByClientId;
    private RentalBaseEntity RentalBaseEntitybyID;
    private int Orders_Id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Order_Score", nullable = false)
    public int getOrderScore() {
        return orderScore;
    }

    public void setOrderScore(int orderScore) {
        this.orderScore = orderScore;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Orders_Id", nullable = false)
    public int getOrders_Id() {
        return Orders_Id;
    }

    public void setOrders_Id(int Orders_Id) {
        this.Orders_Id = Orders_Id;
    }


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Car_Score", nullable = false)
    public int getCarScore() {
        return carScore;
    }

    public void setCarScore(int carScore) {
        this.carScore = carScore;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Rental_Date", nullable = false)
    public Date getRentalDate() {
        return rentalDate;
    }

    public void setRentalDate(Date rentalDate) {
        this.rentalDate = rentalDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Return_Date", nullable = false)
    public Date getReturnDate() {
        return returnDate;
    }

    public void setReturnDate(Date returnDate) {
        this.returnDate = returnDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        OrdersArchiveEntity that = (OrdersArchiveEntity) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                orderScore == that.orderScore &&
                carScore == that.carScore  && Objects.equals(rentalDate, that.rentalDate) &&
                Objects.equals(returnDate, that.returnDate) ;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, orderScore, carScore, rentalDate, returnDate);
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_Base", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    public RentalBaseEntity getRentalBaseEntitybyID() {
        return RentalBaseEntitybyID;
    }

    public void setRentalBaseEntitybyID(RentalBaseEntity RentalBaseEntitybyID) {
        this.RentalBaseEntitybyID = RentalBaseEntitybyID;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Car_Id", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    public CarEntity getCarByCarId() {
        return carByCarId;
    }

    public void setCarByCarId(CarEntity carByCarId) {
        this.carByCarId = carByCarId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Seller_Id", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public SellerEntity getSellerBySellerId() {
        return sellerBySellerId;
    }

    public void setSellerBySellerId(SellerEntity sellerBySellerId) {
        this.sellerBySellerId = sellerBySellerId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Client_Id", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    public ClientEntity getClientByClientId() {
        return clientByClientId;
    }

    public void setClientByClientId(ClientEntity clientByClientId) {
        this.clientByClientId = clientByClientId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the contents of the hibernate query; hint: The elements of the list are not `CarEntity` and not `OrdersArchiveEntity` and you cannot use different first parameters for the columns of the same `TableView`. You won't be able to use `PropertyValueFactory` as `cellValueFactory`s for this kind of `TableView` content. Also why not `select o.carByCarId, o from OrdersArchiveEntity o`?

Comment: The orm you're doing here looks a little strange. You've already set the `OrderArchiveEntity` up so that it has a reference to a `CarEntity`, and you've effectively defined the join between those tables by the annotations in `OrderArchiveEntity`. Doesn't your query replicate the `CarEntity`s, in the sense that you get a list of pairs `(c,o)` with `o.getCarByCarId()==c` for every pair? I think all you need here is `SELECT o FROM OrderArchiveEntity o`, or in shorthand just `FROM OrderArchiveEntity`. Then each row in the table is an `OrderArchiveEntity`, with the `CarEntity` embedded.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: @James_D I tried changing it to FROM OrdersArchiveEntity but still no progress in solving this issue

Comment: @PleaseGiveHelp Ok, but then you need to update everything else. That will give you a `List<OrderArchiveEntity>`, so you can make your table a `TableView<OrderArchiveEntity>` and all your columns `TableColumn<OrderArchiveEntity, Something>`. Then you can do things like `historyColor.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getCarByCarId().getColor()))`

Comment: @James_D thanks! It almost works fine, but how do i set cellData for Date and Double type? Since it's not SimpleStringProperty

Comment: `SimpleDoubleProperty` and `SimpleObjectProperty<Date>`